# Stellar js not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax effect on my website, and I've followed the directions exactly as it says from the [main source](https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js) but it's still not working. Here are the code snippets.

HTML

```
<div id="home-section" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></div>
<div id="site"></div>
```

CSS

```
#home-section {
    background-image: url(inspiration.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
#site {
    height: 4000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

JQ

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.stellar();
</script>
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJoLBW).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is no longer supported, Stellar is not meant to be used with **jQuery** **3.x**. You should see the following error thrown in your dev tools console (or something similar to this):

> Uncaught TypeError: f.getClientRects is not a function

Use a version of **jQuery 2.x** and it will work without any further changes.

Comment: Please make a CodePen, or JsFiddle, or Stack Snippet that shows the issue you're facing.

Comment: It seems that jQuery 3.1.1 is the culprit. Use a jQuery 2.x version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwvVGw